# How to remove validation icon Image in Devexpress ASpxTextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have some ASPxTextboxes in my webPage. I have set requiredFiedvalidate to true.. I have two button on the page.. one is SAVE  and Another is CLEAR. I have set CausesValidation false to CLEAR Button..

Now When User Click on CLear button all the Textboxes gets clear.. and Programs enters into Add Mode...but the validation icons still reamains on the page..

how can i remove that icon? and i also want that icon when user clicks on save buttons if required field is empty..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following [demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/Validation/Inplace.aspx) will be helpful to you.